# phpMyAdmin CentOS 7 cannot log in to the MySQL server

Tags: linux, mysql, centos-7, phpmyadmin, lamp

I am setting up a brand new CentOS 7 LAMP server. I installed phpMyAdmin using yum and epel, following the directions here:
https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-and-secure-phpmyadmin-with-apache-on-centos-7

I am able to log in to MySQL from the command line no problem, with both root and another user I created that we will call fred. However, when I try to log in to phpMyAdmin via a browser (on the server or on another PC) I get this:

> Cannot log in to the MySQL server

That is the extent of the error which makes it very hard to troubleshoot. I have tried logging in with username root, root@localhost, fred, and fred@localhost. I have tried dozens of times doublechecking my passwords which work fine on the command line.

I have searched online and found several posts from people with similar issues, and tried any suggestions I found, none of which helped. I have tried changing different combinations of settings in config.inc.php:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host']      = 'localhost';  // (tried 127.0.0.1)
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';  // (tried http, config)
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user']      = '';        // (tried root, fred)
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password']  = '';        // (tried actual password)
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';  // (tried mysql)
```

With the auth_type set to config, I get a slightly more detailed error:

> Error MySQL said: Cannot connect: invalid settings.
>
> phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server
>   rejected the connection. You should check the host, username and
>   password in your configuration and make sure that they correspond to
>   the information given by the administrator of the MySQL server.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

I found this answer which solved my issue, FYI:

change the auth plugin with:
ALTER USER YOUR_MYSQL_USERNAME IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'YOUR_USER_PASSWORD';

Comment: or ALTER USER 'user_name'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'your_password';